# how to send raw soap request endpoint in php?

Tags: php, curl, soap

Actually my requirement is : I don't want to manually give the SOAP request to the php file by post form action method. And need to receive the raw xml SOAP response over the browser. I used curl to post field to get the response.

Comment: What is your question exactly? What is your issue? What do you want to do precisely?